# Bokeh Wont Render

Tags: flask, bokeh

I have written a very simple flask application to test out Bokeh, however my Bokeh line chart just wont render. All it shows is :

[image]

My html is:

```
<html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-2.0.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            {{graph | safe}}
        </body>
    </html>
```

My flask function is:

```
app.route('/result')
def result():

    x = [1, 3, 5, 7]
    y = [2, 4, 6, 8]

    p = figure()

    p.circle(x, y, size=10, color='red', legend='circle')
    p.line(x, y, color='blue', legend='line')
    p.triangle(y, x, color='gold', size=10, legend='triangle')

    return render_template("result.html", graph=p)
```

The version of bokeh currently installed by pip is 2.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just pass a bare Bokeh object to a Jinja template. There are various Bokeh APIs for embedding the content in different ways. You will need to use one of those:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/2.0.0/docs/user_guide/embed.html

For standalone content like this you either want `json_items`, `components`, or `autoload_static`.